# Core Data fetch predicate with "ANY ... IN" clause not working

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a structure like this:

```
Library 
----------
id: String
name: String
bookIds: NSArray?
```

I want to fetch all Libraries that have some books I look for. Pretty normal stuff, I know. 
This is what I do (and expect to work):

```
    let bookIds: [String] = ...
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Library> = Library.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY bookIds IN %@", bookIds)
```

I have also tried other ways, like this one:

```
    let predicates = bookIds.map {
            NSPredicate(format: "ANY %K LIKE %@", #keyPath(Library.bookIds), $0)
        }
    let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
```

Here is how I use this fetchRequest:

```swift
    librariesFetchController = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: context,
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
            cacheName: nil
        )
```

Comment: What is the CoreData type of the `bookIds` attribute?

Comment: @pbasdf sorry, it's "Transformable".

Comment: The problem with transformables is that they can't easily be included in predicates for fetchRequests (at least not with the SQLite store).  But your use of `bookIds` suggests you should actually be modelling a `Book` object and have a to-many relationship in place of the `bookIds`.

Comment: @pbasdf I did it like you said and it worked! Thanks a lot! I also tried this before, but I didn't store "Book" objects in the related relationship.